# How to hide the header in Google Map?

Tags: html, google-maps, hide

I have created a google map page with two points , I will embed it to my page but how can I hide the div (header) that appears on top

https://jsfiddle.net/095bzndb/

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1yvGgjUjlI4UpAd8f0SqmUW1tf8uHSLSU&hl=de" width="640" height="480"></iframe>

.i4ewOd-pzNkMb-haAclf{

  visibility:hidden;
  display:hide;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.i4ewOd-pzNkMb-haAclf').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

hack it:

```
<div style="height:400px; width:100%; display:inline-block; overflow:hidden;">


<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1yvGgjUjlI4UpAd8f0SqmUW1tf8uHSLSU&hl=de" width="640" height="445" frameborder="0" style="position:relative; top:-50px; border:none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: To this day still the best solution

Comment: confirmed too as of Feb'20